# Suppose $\varnothing\ne A\subseteq\mathbb R$ is closed and that $b \in\mathbb R$. Show there exists $a \in A$ such that $|a-b|=\inf\{|x-a|:x \in A\}$.

Tags: real-analysis, reference-request

Problem: suppose that A is a non-empty closed subset of R and that $b \in R$. Show that there exists $a \in A$ such that $|a-b|=\inf\{|x-b|:x \in A\}$. Is $a$ unique?

I am not sure how to tackle this. A is a closed subset, and $b \in R$. So b is not possibly in A. I am not sure how to construct the existence of $|a-b|=\inf\{|x-b|:x \in A\}$. A hint is appreciated, and related reference is appreciated too.

Comment: See my edits to this question for proper usage in MathJax and in LaTeX. Note: $$ |a-b| = \inf\{|x-a|: x\in A\}. $$

Comment: Is there a typo in your question? Shouldn't it be $\inf\{|x-\color{red}{b}| : x \in A\}$?

Comment: @AnuragA no, i copied right from the book. It's Garling's mathematical analysis

Comment: @spruce Then there is a typo there because $a \in A$ and if you take the infimum for all $x \in A$, then that will be zero because we can have $x=a$. Think of it this way, question wants to find the distance between some point $b$ and the set $A$. The claim is there will be some point in $A$ which will give us the closest distance among all the points and that is how we can define the distance between a point and a set.

Comment: @AnuragA so it should be changed to b not a?

Comment: @spruce yes indeed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Look at $\inf\limits_{x\in A,\ x\geq b}x$, and $\sup\limits_{x\in A,\ x\leq b} x$.